# Python matplot-ting a curve using array append strangely displays lower values at higher positions?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a simple file like below with some text and numbers on it:

```
some text pre 69 some text post
some text pre 63 some text post
some text pre 62 some text post
some text pre 175 some text post
some text pre 57 some text post
some text pre 59 some text post
some text pre 63 some text post
some text pre 58 some text post
some text pre 50 some text post
some text pre 45 some text post
some text pre 46 some text post
some text pre 39 some text post
some text pre 36 some text post
some text pre 39 some text post
some text pre 35 some text post
some text pre 42 some text post
some text pre 36 some text post
some text pre 35 some text post
some text pre 31 some text post
some text pre 34 some text post
some text pre 28 some text post
some text pre 110 some text post
some text pre 25 some text post
some text pre 36 some text post
some text pre 35 some text post
some text pre 21 some text post
some text pre 22 some text post
some text pre 21 some text post
some text pre 34 some text post
some text pre 32 some text post
some text pre 36 some text post
some text pre 34 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 18 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 35 some text post
some text pre 31 some text post
some text pre 35 some text post
some text pre 37 some text post
some text pre 22 some text post
some text pre 24 some text post
some text pre 19 some text post
some text pre 25 some text post
some text pre 21 some text post
some text pre 19 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 19 some text post
some text pre 22 some text post
some text pre 21 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 22 some text post
some text pre 18 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 21 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 19 some text post
some text pre 21 some text post
some text pre 18 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 22 some text post
some text pre 23 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 19 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 21 some text post
some text pre 22 some text post
some text pre 18 some text post
some text pre 26 some text post
some text pre 19 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 20 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 2 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 2 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 2 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 2 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 2 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
some text pre 3 some text post
```

I have *python script* which parses the numbers in the file out into an array and plots a graph based on the array of numbers. Simple. Following is my python script.

```
# Script 1
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import sys

def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

some_text_1 = "some text pre "
some_text_2 = " some text post"

with open("/path/to/file.txt", 'r') as file:
    filetext = file.read()

lines = [line for line in filetext.split('\n') if some_text_1 in line]
numbers_array = []

for x in lines:
    number_in_string = find_between(x, some_text_1, some_text_2)
    if number_in_string:
        number = 0
        number = number_in_string
        numbers_array.append(number)

fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 9), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(numbers_array)
plt.ylabel('Learning python')
plt.show()
```

Following is how the graph appears which is **inexplicably strange! and wrongly plotted**

[image: Incorrect plot]

**How is that the numbers lower in value represented above the higher numbers? What am I doing wrong?**

**But,** if the declare `numbers_array` with some numbers added inline like in below modified script, then the graph plots okay?

```
# Script 2
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

numbers_array = [79, 66, 69, 63, 62, 175, 57, 59, 63, 58, 50, 45, 46, 39, 36, 39, 35, 42, 36, 35, 31, 34, 28, 
            110, 25, 36, 35, 21, 22, 21, 34, 32, 36, 34, 20, 18, 20, 35, 31, 35, 37, 22, 24, 19, 25, 21, 
            19, 20, 19, 22, 21, 20, 22, 18, 20, 21, 20, 20, 19, 21, 18, 20, 20, 20, 20, 22, 23, 20, 19, 
            20, 21, 22, 18, 26, 19, 20, 20, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 48, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
            4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
            4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
            3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3]

fig = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(15, 9), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.plot(numbers_array)
plt.ylabel('Learning python')
plt.show()
```

Following is the plot which looks correct when `numbers_array` is hard coded with random values.

[image: Correct plot]

**Question:**
What am I doing wrong with `Script 1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that in the first script you have a list of strings, not a list of numbers.

The only reason why matplotlib still does not complain is, that it silently proposes that you mean to plot *categories* instead of *numbers*. So each new element is plotted at a next y-level, independent of its value as a number - and the level is named like the element.

---

Example:

```
example_list = ['2', '0', '3', '4', '2', '23', '-5']

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 5))
axs[0].plot(example_list)
axs[0].set_title("plot(['2', '0', '3', '4', '2', '23', '-5'])")
axs[0].set_ylabel('categories')
axs[1].plot([int(i) for i in example_list])
axs[1].set_title('plot([2, 0, 3, 4, 2, 23, -5])')
axs[1].set_ylabel('numbers')
```

[image]

Comment: Wait a minute. I have declared a integer `number = 0`. Then I assign it with the string by doing a `number = number_in_string`. Would that make `number` into a string?

Comment: `number = int(number_in_string)` fixes the whole problem :D

Comment: The point is you do not have to declare variables in python like you do in e.g. C/C++ to define their type. Right after `number = 0` the variable `number` holds the integer number 0 and is indeed of type `int`. But as soon as you assign a string to it, it's a string, and that's what you do one line later.

Comment: I can't suppress to mention that your extraction of the numbers from those text file lines would be easier if you'd use the already imported `re`-module...? And even more if you'd completely leave that manually parsing and use libraries like `numpy` or `pandas`; they provide very convenient importer functions for a variety of data file formats... e.g. [np.genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) or [pd.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that out @SpghttCd. I will read into the numpy libraries and try to improve.